# how to make to gradle's build params work with the dependences' build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my project,I added a dependence like

> compile 'cn.coderyu:library:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

and in the build.gradle file of the library,I hava the configuration

```
manifestPlaceholders.put("SECURITY_FILE",getSecurityFile())

String getSecurityFile() { 
    if (project.hasProperty('HTTPS_CATCHABLE') && project.HTTPS_CATCHABLE.toLowerCase() == 'true' ) { 
        return "@xml/network_security_config" 
     } 
     return "@null" 
}
```

and in the library's manifest file I add

```
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="${SECURITY_FILE}"
        android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
```

when I run the build command

```
gradle assembleRelease -PHTTPS_CATCHABLE=true
```

the manifest file in the released apk is

```
  <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@null"
    android:allowBackup="true" android:label="mytest"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

if I import the library as a submodule ,the command works

Comment: I hava several projects depend on the common library,so I want to do this config in the library rather than each project